# Spark Dataframe considering String as Integer

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a couple of csv files that I am reading using Spark. Each of the files have the same number of columns.

```
StructType(List(
  StructField(date,IntegerType,true),
  StructField(Market,StringType,true),
  StructField(BrandName,StringType,true),
  StructField(RetailerName,StringType,true)))
```

One such column is having the name ***date*** with values in the  format 'MM/dd/yyyy'

Theoretically, I believe, if no explicit schema is specified, by means of `option("schema",schema)` or `option("inferSchema","true")` , all columns must be interpreted as of StringType().

However to my surprise, this `date` column is interpreted as an `integer/IntegerType()`. To force inference of date column as String, I passed in a custom schema with all my columns specified as StringType. Even then, the value is interpreted as integer.

Finally when I try to print the contents of the dataframe using `display(df)`, I get the following error:

```
Error while reading file: file1.csv ,Caused by: IllegalArgumentException: 
  requirement failed: requiredSchema  should be the subset of dataSchema
```

Why could this be happening? How could I overcome this?

Comment: Just to be clear when reading the CSV with explicit`inferSchema=false` you get a df with `date` column as Integer ?

Comment: @gatear Yes. And one more thing, the location that I am reading from is partitioned by month and date. Sample values could be month=202112 and date=20211210

Comment: Not sure is that is confusing Spark in some way.

Comment: That explains it, so the dataset is partitioned by date where date is an int.
Why not read the CSV with no schema inferred and cast the date int to a date string using a simple `select` ?